How to remove <![CDATA [ .... ]]> in OSB 12c
We have a message coming in OSB JMS poller proxy in text format, which does MFL transformation and converts that into xml.
The issue is, sometimes, the file has <![CDATA [ ....   ]]>, and also addes an extra line, which causes the MFL to fail.
for example, the file sometimes looks like:
389545265
Gregory Alles
29 Harbour St

Castle Hill
4150
VIC

<![CDATA [Please note that the medical evidence must
 be provided.]]>
95.00

The correct file format should be:
389545265
Gregory Alles
29 Harbour St

Castle Hill
4150
VIC

Please note that the medical evidence must be provided.
95.00

Is there anything we can do in the OSB (before the MFL transformation), as a workaround to remove the CDATA and additional line?
The source system which is sending this request, doesn't have an option to correct this, hence looking for any workaround in OSB.
Thanks in advance,
Vivek
